# Shell commands in Vim vs. Neovim?

Tags: shell

When I run a shell command in Neovim like `:!ls` the results come up in a little minibuffer.

In Vim, the Vim instance is temporarily closed and the results are printed to the terminal without my terminal syntax highlighting (oh my zsh).

Is there a way to create the same behavior in Vim that I experience in Neovim?

Comment: Try https://github.com/fcpg/vim-altscreen.

Comment: :term is what I was looking for. Thanks Balki

Comment: @balki please post answers in an Answer below, not in comments